# Amazon S3 Versions: log one line per version

Tags: amazon-s3

Before I go down this rabbit hole, has anybody tried this? Is it crazy?

Let's say I want to put a log file in Amazon S3. But S3 doesn't have the ability to append to an existing object without first reading the object, then appending, then writing back, so it becomes increasingly expensive to write each new line in the log file.

Can I do this instead? Every time I append a new line, simply write that line as the entire contents of the s3 object. With versions turned on, each version would be a single line of the log file, and I could retrieve the entire log file by retrieving all versions. If each log file is billions of lines, then this might be bad, but in my case, it'll be more like a few thousand.

Could this work? Any reason not to do it?

Comment: I've no experience of this but I think it's worth asking amazon how many versions they support and what happens when you hit the cap as you may come across some nasty consequences. Other options 1) rotate your files more often so that you're not appending 2) use s3fs with caching mode so that writes are done asynchronously

Comment: Did you ever end up trying this? I'm curious if it works.

Comment: I didn't. I asked amazon at their 'startup loft' in SF about it, and I think they recommended against this, but I can't remember why. What I really wanted to do is basically a 'reliable persistent queue in the cloud'. I just did it another way.

Answer (score 1):

You "can" but that doesn't necessarily make it a good idea.

Replacing a large object isn't more expensive than creating a new version that is small -- the price is the same, which makes the cost essentially the same since there isn't a charge for the data transfer between s3 and ec2 within a region.

Moving the old logs into s3 with `logrotate` every time they rotate would probably be better.

A more cloud-ish way to collect logs might be SQS or Kinesis, depending on volume.